# Using custom ports with iOS IKEv2 VPN config?

Tags: ios, vpn

We have already set up a strongSwan IKEv2 VPN server, which can be connected by the iOS VPN APP we developed.
However, we've been asked to change the default port that the VPN server listens to "to raise the security level".
Is there any way to change the port used by the IKEv2 protocol on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't possible to change the IKE and NAT-T ports if using the `NEVPNProtocolIKEv2`.

A similar question has been asked on the Apple Developer forums here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/82304

I'm not really sure how this will "raise the security level" as the packets will still be easily detectable as IKE and ESP, but if you need to do things like this you will need to implement your VPN using `NEPacketTunnelProvider`.